# Encode problems webscraping

Tags: python

I try to solve the encoding problem, but it does not work.

I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "amazon.py", line 49, in <module>
    outfile=(data.encode('utf8'))
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# coding: utf-8

from selectorlib import Extractor
import requests 
import json 
import encodings
from time import sleep



# Create an Extractor by reading from the YAML file
e = Extractor.from_yaml_file('selectors.yml')

def scrape(url):    
    headers = {
        'authority': 'www.amazon.com',
        'pragma': 'no-cache',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'dnt': '1',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 8172.45.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.64 Safari/537.36',
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
        'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    }

    # Download the page using requests
    print("Downloading %s"%url)
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    # Simple check to check if page was blocked (Usually 503)
    if r.status_code > 500:
        if "To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact" in r.text:
            print("Page %s was blocked by Amazon. Please try using better proxies\n"%url)
        else:
            print("Page %s must have been blocked by Amazon as the status code was %d"%(url,r.status_code))
        return None
    # Pass the HTML of the page and create 
    return e.extract(r.text)

# product_data = []
with open("urls.txt",'r') as urllist, open('output.jsonl','w') as outfile:
    for url in urllist.readlines():
        data = scrape(url) 
        if data:
            json.dump(data,outfile)
            outfile=(data.encode('utf8'))
            outfile.write("\n")
            # sleep(5)
```

Comment: The line `json.dump(data,outfile)` already writes the object `data` as a JSON string into the fileobject `outfile`. Thus, I'd just take out the line `outfile=(data.encode('utf8'))`. Note that you'd not be getting a valid JSON file seeing as you're writing it out in a loop but that's a different problem.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel normally, i should have this type of content, but not yet!

 Montre Connectée Thermomètre Cardiofréquencemètre Bracelet Connecté Podomètre ECG GPS Fitness Tracker d’Activité Tension Artérielle Smartwatch Sport Étanche IP68 Montre Cardio (Noir) 


i have this, one...

 "Montre Connect\u00e9e Thermom\u00e8tre Cardiofr\u00e9quencem\u00e8tre Bracelet Connect\u00e9 Podom\u00e8tre ECG GPS Fitness Tracker d\u2019Activit\u00e9 Tension Art\u00e9rielle Smartwatch Sport \u00c9tanche IP68 Montre Cardio (Noir)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by using:

```
json.dump(data,outfile,ensure_ascii=False)
```